# Discrepancies in Gmail Postmaster Tools Reporting for SPF, DKIM, and DMARC Despite Positive DMARC Reports

Tags: gmail, spf, dkim, dmarc

I'm facing a perplexing issue with Gmail's Postmaster Tools regarding the reporting of SPF, DKIM, and DMARC for emails sent to Gmail addresses. Despite the email headers and third-party validation tools indicating that SPF, DKIM, and DMARC are correctly configured and passing, Gmail's Postmaster Tools reports failures in DMARC and DKIM.

Here's a detailed outline of the situation:

Gmail Postmaster Tools Issue: Reports failures in DMARC and DKIM.

Email Headers: Indicate that SPF, DKIM, and DMARC are passing.

Third-party Tools: Confirm that my SPF, DKIM, and DMARC configurations are correct.

DMARC Reports: Specifically, DMARC aggregate reports from Google show that SPF and DKIM are passing (see the example report below).

```
<feedback>
  ...
  <policy_published>
    <domain>domain.com</domain>
    <adkim>r</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>quarantine</p>
    <sp>quarantine</sp>
    <pct>100</pct>
    <np>quarantine</np>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>82.223.xx.xxx</source_ip>
      <count>29</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    ...
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>domain.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>nvio</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>sub.domain.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
</feedback>
```

And this is the postmaster "Authenticated Traffic". Don't ask me for the glitch of 25th. It's a mystery.

[image]

**Additional info:**

There is no _dmarc.sub.domain.com txt record.
The _dmarc.domain.com txt record is : "v=DMARC1;p=quarantine;pct=100;rua=mailto:dmarcreports@****;ruf=mailto:dmarcreports@****"

SPF is for sub.domain.com

The **Return-path** and the mta **MAIL FROM:** is for sub.domain.com

The **From:** header is from domain.com

The **DKIM selector** is: selector._domainkey.domain.com

Comment: Are there other sources that are sending email? Are there other XMLs containing records of emails failing DKIM and passing SPF on unaligned domains (`Return-Path`)?
I'm not that familiar with postmaster, but it seems like you have other sources sending on your domain's behalf too.

Comment: @Reinto Yes there are other sources and there are failures in both dkim and passing spf, the opposite and failure in both, bat the report say 100% fail, not 12% or whatever. The reports of mxtookbox or mail tester say nothing about unaligned domains failure.